# Prove that if a linear combination of the rows equals the zero row AND a linear combination of the b's equals zero iff Ax=b has a solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if a linear combination of the rows equals the zero row AND a linear combination of the b's equals zero iff Ax=b has a solution.

I can prove this in a roundabout way using $x^T (A^T y) = (Ax)^T y$ but I am looking for a simpler proof.

Comment: _Linear combination of $b$'s?_

Comment: @Invisible $y^T b$